# how can I capture images from two cameras simultaneously with a computer?

Tags: tethering

I would like to be able to preview and capture photos from two cameras simultaneously, and download them to my computer. Being able to keep track of which photos were from which camera is also a must.

I haven't bought the cameras yet, and I do not have any requirements as to which cameras are supported (it seems the packages above only support Canons). On the other hand I need a digital camera with 1024*1280 pixel resolution.

I also want to control the capturing step and frequency with software on my computer.

My requirement is about 20 pictures per minute.

What's the best model camera and software for this purpose?

And how I can connect these camera to my computer?

Comment: How close does "simultaneous" have to be?  That makes a huge difference in what will or won't work.  Also, if the answer to that question is "as close as possible" then what kind of budget are you working with?

Comment: Are you planning to create stereoscopic images? Or 3D video? Because that case probably you are way better off with an already existing solution...

Comment: Related previous question: [How can I trigger multiple cameras to fire simultaneously?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9326/how-can-i-trigger-multiple-cameras-to-fire-simultaneously)